# What's the logic for determining a min/max vector in GLSL?

Tags: glsl

I'm a bit surprised I don't know this already, but it never hurts to admit you're still learning :)

In GLSL there are `min` and `max` functions that that, according to their [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/min.xml):

> return the lesser/greater of two values

But how is that determined when the values are vectors? Obviously `(1, 1)` would be less than `(2, 2)`, but what is the min or max of `(1, 3)` and `(4, -2)`? Where is that logic formally described?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Quoting from the [first source that I could find](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.30.6.pdf) (PDF), at the top of §8.3 Common Functions, page 132:

> These all operate component-wise. The description is per component.

Nearly all the functions that operator on vectors but really only make sense for a scalar operate component-wise. (This includes `abs`, `sign`, `floor`, `trunc`, `round`, `roundEven`, `ceil`, `fract`, `mod`, `modf`, `min`, `max`, `clamp`, `mix`, `step`, `smoothstep`, and a whole lot more.)

So, for example, the min of `(1, 3)` and `(4, -2)` is `(1, -2)`.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I assumed, but I was having a tough time finding documentation to verify it. Thanks!